# Incorrect mouse event zooming in windows surface using easeljs / createjs

Tags: javascript, zooming, easeljs, createjs, tablet-pc

I have a website that uses CreateJS and canvas. Some objects have associated a click event. Works well in browsers and mobile devices, except in windows surface.

If I zoom in windows surface the click event is lost when the screen moves. Only works well when matched (0,0) to the screen.

Example:

http://intelisen.com/apok/simple.html

Zooming and moving no longer works circle click event.

Any suggestions?

Thank You